# How to draw a rectangle inner inside end triangle shape in xml drawable android?

Tags: android, xml, vector, drawable, shapes

I want to draw a shape same like below (in light blue color) so that I can put it as background for TextViews -

[image]

Obviously it could be easy if I just needed to draw a rectangle but in shape I want a inner triangle too.

Help me if anyone ever tried this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this as well

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:viewportWidth="100.0"
        android:viewportHeight="100.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#8BC34A"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 90,50 100,100 0,100 z"/>
</vector>
```

and your **TextView** as:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_id"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_margin"
android:background="@drawable/you_drawable_here"
android:gravity="start|center"
android:paddingEnd="20dp"
android:text="your text here"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Its the same what I need. but the only drawback is, height getting reduce when add long text.

Answer (score 2):

you can create SVG first then convert it to Vector

Updated :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M526.63 383.78l-466.32 0 0 -234.7"
        android:fillColor="#3498DB" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M526.63 383.78L417.45 266.43 526.63 151.12 60.31 150"
        android:fillColor="#3498DB"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: It is showing a white diagonal line, can we remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this drawable file and set as a backgroud for desired view:

**Ribbon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M526.63 383.78l-466.32 0 0 -234.7"
        android:fillColor="#3498DB" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M526.63 383.78L417.45 266.43 526.63 151.12 60.31 149.08"
        android:fillColor="#3498DB"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: But I am getting problem while setting it as background on a textview, it's not usual as we use simple draw able shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:name="dark_triangle"
        android:fillColor="#5ad0e6"
        android:pathData="M 10,0 L 0,100 100,100 z" />

    <path
        android:name="light_triangle"
        android:fillColor="#5ad0e6"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z" />

</vector>
```